# Can phpCake be tweaked to accept db name object names that do not comply with it's convention

Tags: mysql, cakephp

We have an existing mysql db that breaks many off phpCakes naming convention rules (table names, column and key names... the works.)  Making the changes to the schema to satisfy phpCake will require a lot of time.  There are other apps using the db, and plenty on SPs, triggers and the like that will also need changes.
Is there a way to tweak cake's convention standard to get around this? 
Also it seems as tho we have to "discover" cake's requirements in this regard as we go along.  Is there a document that lays out phpcake naming requirements in detail?

Comment: phpCake? You mean CakePHP surely? Also you should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a different table for your models.
Simply set the $useTable var:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    // by default looks for "users" table
    public $useTable = 'strange_Users_table123';
}
```

Note that you should try to use "users", though, if possible.
But as you can see the conventions can easily be worked around using some more configuration.